# WebService Parser Error

Tags: c#, web-services

I've created a web service (hello world) in VS and when I run the web service I get the following error message:

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'UpdaterWS.Service1'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Service1.asmx.cs"
>   Class="UpdaterWS.Service1" %>

How can I fix this?

code:

```
namespace WebService1HelloTest
{
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
 public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
[WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code here...

Comment: public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }

Comment: is it in namespace UpdaterWS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you rebuilt after adding the service?

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your service is in the `WebService1HelloTest` namespace, but you're referring to the `UpdaterWS` namespace.

Why are you using ASMX services in any case? That's a legacy technology that shouldn't be used for new development.

Comment: Just because it is legacy doesn't mean it can't be used.  What if it is legacy system that is still utilizing asmx?

Comment: @Xaisoft: If the system needs to be .NET 2.0 or before, that would be a reason to use it. It's your choice, of course, but most people prefer to use software that the vendor will fix if there are bugs. Microsoft is fixing only the most critical bugs in ASMX and the XML Serializer.

Comment: @Xaisoft: BTW, do you understand that "legacy" in this instance means "we left ASMX in .NET because of code that already uses it, not because we want you to use it for new code"?

Comment: I agree with your point.  If you have the option to use something else such as WCF, go ahead, but if you are still in .NET 2 or before land, as many people are, you have no choice but to continue with asmx.

Comment: @Xaisoft: I have never suggested not to use legacy technology on legacy .NET versions or legacy operating systems.

Comment: I get what you are saying, no need to go any further with it.

Answer (score 0):

As John Saunders said, your service is in the WebService1HelloTest namespace, but you're referring to the UpdaterWS namespace.

To fix it, right click on your WebService1HelloTest.asmx file and select View Markup. You will see that your Class is referring to UpdaterWS.Service1. Change it to WebService1HelloTest.HelloWorld and you should be ready to go.